# what is the difference between these two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written two queries to check the differences between two tables, both shown below. Query 2 shows me the correct results.

In each table there is one record that is not in the other. So I wanted a query which would show both these records, which Query 2 does. It show me the 90 rows where the tables match plus another 2 rows, one where a record is in tblIH but not in tblTempN and another record which is in tblTempN but not in tblIH.

Whereas Query 1 shows me only the 90 records where the tables match and one extra row where the record is in tblIH but not in tblTempN - it does NOT however show me the record in tblTempN which is not in tblIH - why? I thought using a full outer join would show me all records from both tables? I don't really understand the difference between the two queries as they seem the same to me?

**Query 1**

```
select coalesce(h.Sedol, nav.Sedol) Sedol,  
       coalesce(nav.Name, h.Name) Name, 
       isnull(h.Nominal, 0) - isnull(nav.Nominal, 0) NomDiff
  from tblIH h full outer join tblTempN nav 
    on h.Sedol = nav.Sedol and h.Code = nav.Code
 where h.FundCode = 'ABC' and h.DatePrice = '2015-03-20'
```

**Query 2**

```
;with hld as
(
    select Sedol, Name, FX, Nominal from tblIH
    where DatePrice = '2015-03-20' and FundCode = 'ABC'
), nav as
(
    select Sedol, Name, Nominal from tblTempN
    where DateAcc = '2015-03-20' and FundCode = 'ABC'
)
select coalesce(hld.Sedol, nav.Sedol) Sedol,  
       coalesce(nav.Name, hld.Name) Name, 
       isnull(hld.Nominal, 0) - isnull(nav.Nominal, 0) NomDiff 
  from hld full outer join nav
    on hld.Sedol = nav.Sedol
```

Comment: In your first query you don't have two where condition `DateAcc = '2015-03-20' and FundCode = 'ABC'` on `tbletemp` table but in second query you have these conditions in corresponding `with` clause

Comment: `where h.FundCode = 'ABC' and h.DatePrice = '2015-03-20' ` is the porblem maybe?

Comment: q1 is in practice an inner join. q2 is full outer join.

Comment: Your first query is actually a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Why is my first query a left or inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `full outer join` if you don't have satisfied condition field values from that table fetched as null

I suppose you missed to write conditions 
`nav.FundCode = 'ABC' and nav.DatePrice = '2015-03-20'`

but apart from this you are missing one more fundamental that `where` clause will be applicable on the result from that `full outer join`.

So actually you are getting 90+1+1 out of full outer join but your `where` condition is filtering one record from this result because for one desired record h.FundCode and h.DatePrice value is NULL.

You can use `NVL` function while checking for these condition.